# Extract underlying value_type from the container

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to extract *value* type from the container. It turns out that most std containers have a `value_type`, but maps, unfortunately, use it for other purposes.

So, I have tried to create a code that could extract the underlying data type from the container taking the above into account:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct IsMap : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct IsMap<T, std::enable_if_t<
                    std::is_same<typename T::value_type,
                                std::pair<const typename T::key_type,
                                            typename T::mapped_type>
                    >::value>
> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Container>
using ValueTypeFrom = std::conditional_t<IsMap<Container>::value, 
    typename Container::mapped_type, typename Container::value_type>;
```

Here is the use case:

```
template<typename Container>
std::set<ValueTypeFrom<Container>> ToSet(const Container& container) {
    return std::set<ValueTypeFrom<Container>>(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}
```

The code successfully extracts and compiles with `std::map`, however the more basic case for `std::vector` fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the `ValueTypeFrom` trait is not SFINAE-friendly, because `typename Container::mapped_type, typename Container::value_type` will both be attempted when passing a specific `Container` to `ValueTypeFrom`, resulting in an error upon instantiating `std::conditional`.

The reason why you had no error in the case of `std::map` is that `std::map` happens to have both `mapped_type` and `value_type`. So the code was not working in that case too. Or it was working by luck, if you like.

What you need to do, is to give `std::conditional_t` two things which will not try to access `::value_type`/`::mapped_type` directly in the contex of `std::conditional`'s instantiation, but two things that, upon you trying to instatiate them, will do so. And clearly you want `std::conditional_t` to give **only one** of these two things back to you, so that you can indeed `::type` it and not the other one.

The two things are the `ValueTypeT` and `MappedTypeT` classes in the code below.

The presence of `MappedTypeT<Container>` and `ValueTypeT<Container>` do not trigger the instantiations of `MappedTypeT` and `ValueTypeT` for the specific `Container` you pass to the trait, thus the extraction of `::value_type`/`::mapped_type` is not even attemped yet.

What you get back from `std::conditional_t` is *either* `ValueTypeT` or `MappedTypeT`, so when you do `typename thatthing::type`, you're effectively querying the `::type` memeber only of the relevant of the two.

Here's the complete exmaple:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct ValueTypeT  {
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct MappedTypeT {
    using type = typename T::mapped_type;
};

template<typename Container>
using ValueTypeFrom = typename std::conditional_t<
    IsMap<Container>::value,
    MappedTypeT<Container>,
    ValueTypeT<Container>
    >::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<ValueTypeFrom<std::vector<int>>, int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<ValueTypeFrom<std::map<int,int>>, int>);
```

---

This stuff is explained in great detail in *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide - 2nd edition* at pages 440-443, §19.7.1.

---

Also notice that if you can use the Range-v3 library, making a `std::set` out of a `std::vector`'s values or `std::map`'s mapped values is as easy as

```cpp
auto s1 = vec | to<std::set>;
auto s2 = map | values | to<std::set>;
```

so you could write this code somewhere in place where you need it, or in two branches of an `if constexpr`. Just to say.